# findcontours finds too many contours

Tags: opencv

Is it normal that find contours finds so many contours where there are obviously only 3 contours ?

The original image and after drawing found contours are shown below : 
[image]

[image]

The code is :

```
Mat image;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    image = imread(argv[1], 0);   // Read the file
    findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    cout << contours.size();


    RNG rng(12345);
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }
    /// Show in a window
    namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Contours", drawing);
namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image);                   // Show our image inside it.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are Reading a Jpeg or any other compressed version of your actual input image which adds these noise. Find contours needs Binary image. If you want to process this image simple apply threshold before finding contours! Note that your source image is working fine for me!
[image]

Comment: You are right, I used the PNG version of the image and findContours worked properly. I inspected the Jped image and it was non-binary(some noise) So when saving a binary image in Jpeg it becomes non binary !